# storing a structure object at void pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

Assuming I have the following code:

```
struct inst {
    uint32_t field1;
    uint16_t field2;
   void *priv;
};

struct ops {
    int (*init)(void);
    int (*deinit)(void);
    int (*run)(void);
};
```

Therefore I can do:

```
struct inst p1;
struct ops ops;

/* init p1 and ops.*/
...

inst->priv = ops;
```

Is it safe later access the data in `priv` this way:

```
return (struct ops *)inst->priv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inst->priv = ops;
```

Shouldn't it be

```
inst->priv = &ops;
```

Also, to get to your question, "Is it safe later access the data in priv this way:", no it isn't. It depends where you are creating the structures instances. If you are creating like this

```
struct ops * dummyA()
{
    struct inst p1;
    struct ops ops;
    //(...)
    inst->priv = (void*)&ops;
    //(...)
    return (struct ops *)inst->priv;
}
```

it isn't safe because those structures where created in the stack inside the function and therefore, their memory address will be marked as free right when you leave the function.

A way to get around this is to use the heap (malloc) or (maybe the easier way) declare the structures like this:

```
static struct inst p1;
static struct ops ops;
```

This way you don't need to worry about memory allocation and you are certain those stack elements will never be erased until the end of the program and therefore you can use their pointers as you wish.

Comment: thanks for feedback. I'm aware of issues with returning stack-allocated objects, and my question was rather about typecasting in `return (struct ops *)inst->priv` -- is it required, or can be omitted?

Comment: But don't return stack pointers. It will not do what you intend it to do.